# Convert ASCII int to char

Tags: c#, cypher, ascii

I have some code which is the beginning of a Caesar cypher using the ASCII value of a char and then adding to that value to shift it.

At the moment I have converted it back to a string to print the shifted ASCII values to TextBox3. But I need to convert 'result' back to chars in order to display the encrypted string. This is what I am struggling with.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = textBox1.Text;
    int shift = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        int inputInt = Convert.ToInt32(c);

        int result = shift + inputInt;

        string output = Convert.ToString(result);

        textBox3.Text += output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some sample input and expected output? Because what you have there is not a Caesar cypher.

Comment: Some text would be put into TextBox1 say 'my name'. Text box 2 is the number to add to each ASCII value, So say 3. So for the char m, 'result' would be 109 (ASCII value for 'm') + 3. so the first number in Textbox3 would be 112. Correct, Its not a traditional Ceasar Cypher.

Comment: So I need to convert the 112 to its char which is 'p'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string input = textBox1.Text;
    int shift = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        int inputInt = (int)c;

        int result = shift + inputInt;

        // result > 255?

        textBox3.Text += (char)result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string input = textBox1.Text;
  int shift = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

  textBox3.Text=string.Join("", input.Select(charr => (char)(((int)charr) + shift))
                                );
```